# Element not found in cache perhaps the page has changed since it has lookedup, selenium webdriver

Tags: java, excel, selenium

Selenium WebDriver:

I have a excel sheet with users having multiple skills, the single user has multiple skills with multiple rows and I am entering that data dynamically in the portal by checking the usernames from home page in UI and name in excelsheet, if it matches it clicks the user in the UI where it navigates to other page and other function returns the no of rows user has in excel sheet and fetches the data row by row cell by cell for all rows user has and adds in the portal one by one.
Now when clicked on home page to go back and perform the operation where the webelements is left over to verify the other users match for the remaining, it is throwing staleelement exception.

Error shown:

```
Element not found in cache perhaps the page has changed after looked.
```

Error line:

```
String [] str = webElement.getText().split("\n");
```

I tried `thread.sleep` before clicking element, I tried `try/catch` but nothing is working, as I need other user data which has in Excel sheet to be compared with the remaining web element which is user names and click the next match to enter the matching user data again row by row cell by cell.

Please help, I am trying this from past 4 days and couldn’t figure out how to get continue further to get the others users data to enter in portal.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    WebElement NamePath=driver.findElement(By.xpath(ReadPropertyFile.readProperty("ClickNamePath")));
    java.util.List<WebElement> ListPath1 = driver.findElements(By.xpath((ReadPropertyFile.readProperty("ClickNamePath"))));
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    Iterator<WebElement> itWebelement = ListPath1.iterator();

    while(itWebelement.hasNext())
            {
            WebElement webElement = itWebelement.next();
            String [] str = webElement.getText().split("\n"); 
            String var= str[0];
            System.out.println(var);

        String FilePath1= "D:\\pcdp10012016_demo.xlsx";
        FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(FilePath1));
        XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(inputStream);
        XSSFSheet sheet1= wb.getSheetAt(0);
        List<EmployeePCDPDTO> pcdpDtoObject=ReadExcelData.ReadData(sheet1, var);

                    if(!pcdpDtoObject.isEmpty()){
        webElement.click();
        Iterator<EmployeePCDPDTO> itEmployeepcdpList = pcdpDtoObject.iterator();

            while(itEmployeepcdpList.hasNext())
            {
            EmployeePCDPDTO employeePCDPDTO = itEmployeepcdpList.next();

            Thread.sleep(3000);
            WebElement Addbtn=driver.findElement(By.xpath(ReadPropertyFile.readProperty("AddSkillPath")));
                             Addbtn.click();
                            Thread.sleep(3000);     

                            //select SkillType
                            WebElement s= driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='skillTypeDropdown']"));
                            Select oselect= new Select(s);
                            oselect.selectByValue(employeePCDPDTO.getSkillType());
                            Thread.sleep(3000);
                            driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='skillName']")).clear();
                             driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='skillName']")).sendKeys(employeePCDPDTO.getSkillName());
                            Thread.sleep(3000);
                            //store button
                            driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='add-edit-box']/div[7]/div/button[2]")).click();


            }
                    //Home page path in UI
                    Thread.sleep(3000);
                    //home page button
                    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='app']/div/div/div[1]/ol/li[1]/a")).click();
                    Thread.sleep(5000);
        }
                    } 
            }
    }
```

Comment: Problem here is your are navigating to another page from home page. Again you are coming back to home. So you are revisiting the home page again and again you should re identify again all web element.

Comment: The error says it all `Element not found in cache perhaps the page has changed after looked.`. You are doing `String [] str = webElement.getText().split("\n"); ` after you are moving to the next page through `WebElement webElement = itWebelement.next();` So webdriver is unable to find the element after the DOM is refreshed.

Comment: Issue solved with the below block of code and removed click from these for loops

Answer (score 0):

I have changed few lines. Please try the following code and let me know.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception { 
    WebElement NamePath=driver.findElement(By.xpath(ReadPropertyFile.readProperty("ClickNamePath"))); 
    java.util.List<WebElement> ListPath1 =               driver.findElements(By.xpath((ReadPropertyFile.readProperty("ClickNamePath")))); 
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    // Iterator<WebElement> itWebelement = ListPath1.iterator();
    //while(itWebelement.hasNext())
   for(int i=0; i < ListPath1.size();i++){ 
         WebElement webElement = itWebelement.get(i); 
         String [] str = webElement.getText().split("\n");
         String var= str[0];      
         System.out.println(var); 
         String FilePath1= "D:\\pcdp10012016_demo.xlsx";      
         FileInputStream inputStream = new 
       FileInputStream(new File(FilePath1));    
      XSSFWorkbook wb = new         XSSFWorkbook(inputStream);      
        XSSFSheet sheet1= wb.getSheetAt(0); 
         List<EmployeePCDPDTO> pcdpDtoObject=ReadExcelData.ReadData(sheet1, var);
          if(!pcdpDtoObject.isEmpty()){ webElement.click(); Iterator<EmployeePCDPDTO> itEmployeepcdpList = pcdpDtoObject.iterator(); while(itEmployeepcdpList.hasNext()) { EmployeePCDPDTO employeePCDPDTO = itEmployeepcdpList.next(); Thread.sleep(3000); WebElement Addbtn=driver.findElement(By.xpath(ReadPropertyFile.readProperty("AddSkillPath"))); Addbtn.click(); Thread.sleep(3000); //select SkillType WebElement s= driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='skillTypeDropdown']")); Select oselect= new Select(s); oselect.selectByValue(employeePCDPDTO.getSkillType()); Thread.sleep(3000); driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='skillName']")).clear(); driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='skillName']")).sendKeys(employeePCDPDTO.getSkillName()); Thread.sleep(3000); //store button driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='add-edit-box']/div[7]/div/button[2]")).click(); } //Home page path in UI Thread.sleep(3000); //home page button driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='app']/div/div/div[1]/ol/li[1]/a")).click(); Thread.sleep(5000); } }ListPath1 =               driver.findElements(By.xpath((ReadPropertyFile.readProperty("ClickNamePath")))); } }
```

Comment: thanks for responding to my query, I am getting same staleelement error in the same line of code 'String [] str = webElement.getText().split("\n"); with the above changes as well. '.please help if there is any other solution to keep the webelement in cache for it not to throw staleerror

Answer (score 0):

```
        for (int i = 0; i < ListPath1.size(); i++) {

            count++;

            if(count>1){

            for(int j=0;j<=2;j++)

            {

                try{

                java.util.List<WebElement> ListPath2 = driver.findElements(By.xpath((ReadPropertyFile.readProperty("ClickNamePath"))));

                webElement = ListPath2.get(count-1);

                String[] str = webElement.getText().split("\n");

                var = str[0];

                System.out.println(var);



                break;

            }

                catch(Exception e)

                {

                    System.out.println(e.getMessage());

                }

            }

            }else{

            webElement = ListPath1.get(i);

            String[] str = webElement.getText().split("\n");

            var = str[0];

            System.out.println(var);

            }
```